# How to set payload on MenuItem using .NET Client Mirror API?

Tags: .net, google-mirror-api

Trying to set action to OPEN_URI on a MenuItem Action.

Here's my Code:

```
    TimelineItem item2 = new TimelineItem()
        {
            Creator = new Contact()
            {
                DisplayName = "Joaquin Quick Start",
                PhoneNumber = "+XXXXXXXX",
                Id = "JOAQUIN_QUICKSTART",
            },
            Text = "Buenos Dias ",
            SpeakableText = "Good morning",
            Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" },

            MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>() { { new MenuItem() {Action ="CUSTOM", Id="complete", Values= new List<MenuValue>() {
                new MenuValue() {DisplayName="Complete",IconUrl="http://app.sfy.com/glass/ic_bed_50.png"}
            }}},
            { new MenuItem() { Action ="OPEN_URI"}},
            { new MenuItem() { Action ="NAVIGATE"}},
            { new MenuItem() { Action ="VOICE_CALL"}},
        }
        };
        item2.BundleId = item.BundleId;
        controller.Service.Timeline.Insert(item2).Fetch();
```

How can I set the payload for the action OPEN_URI ?

```
  { new MenuItem() { Action ="OPEN_URI"}},
```

The property is exposed in the API

https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert

"
menuItems[].payload string  A generic payload whose meaning changes depending on this MenuItem's action.
When the action is OPEN_URI, the payload is the URL of the website to view.
When the action is PLAY_VIDEO, the payload is the streaming URL of the video
writable
"

But I can't find a way to set the payload.

The only idea that comes to my mind is  to use a direct http post, with the json.

The problem was that the Quickstart .NET project includes version 1.3 of the Mirror TimeLine APi.

I had to remove the former, and add the new version using:

install-package Google.Apis.Mirror.v1 -Pre

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mirror/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Mirror_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1MenuItem.html#a8304b5c3cbacf8d5794318052629b97f) says this is a settable property, so if I understand .NET correctly, you should be able to do something like

```
{ new MenuItem() { Action="OPEN_URI", Payload="http://example.com/" } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that, but that property is not exposed in the current version of the .NET Api

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Its actually a version problem.  You're probably using version mirror api version 1.3.0.15233 (or close to it).  This is what comes with the quickstart, but isn't the latest greatest version.

I updated to version 1.6.0.33 of Google.Apis.Mirror.v1 and was able to add the payload.  I know this is no longer the latest version, but I assume it will still work in the latest version.  You can get the latest version on nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Mirror.v1/

Beware: you'll need to make some additional changes.  For example, when you make a call like  Service.Timeline.Insert(MyCard).Fetch(); you will see that in version 1.6.0.33, that "Fetch()" isn't valid.  You'll need to change to "Execute()". The changes are relatively trivial, but they will break some existing code when you upgrade.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does video play back works ok with this version?, i'm using older version of mirrorapi--.dll where i stream the video which used to work, not now, it is a open bug. (https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=387)

Comment: I've also tried upgrading to a newer version. But as authentication changes from 1.7 on, then all the code in the sample has to be modified.

Thanks